# Sometimes results are not showing when using WHERE clause in PHP Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, where-clause

This is my SQL table

[image]

when I try to fetch record with PDO using this mysqli query:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `tags` = ? LIMIT 25
```

**? is replaced by a $_GET variable.**

so for example i want to get results for this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1` WHERE `tags` = 'a' LIMIT 25
```

it will load and for other parameters, it does not load. but when I run a sql query in phpmyadmin the query loads without error(Always)! 
Can someone help me to understand why it is happening?

Comment: Storing comma separated lists is an anti-pattern.  https://www.amazon.com/SQL-Antipatterns-Programming-Pragmatic-Programmers/dp/1934356557  Note that there are no rows that satisfy the condition `tags = 'a'`.     MySQL does provide `FIND_IN_SET` function... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set   e.g. `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('a','a,b,c')`   e.g. `SELECT t.id, t.tags FROM mytable t WHERE FIND_IN_SET('a',t.tags) ORDER BY t.id`

Comment: Why is this tagged as "pdo"? You state *"...WHERE clause in PHP **Mysqli**"*. < That is a different animal than PDO.

Comment: @spencer7593 look at the image in my question, you can see the first & 7th column has value 'a' in it.

Comment: @Dry7 I have added a picture in the answer kindly take a look!

Comment: @Mayuresh:  rows 1 and 7 do NOT satisfy the condition  `tags = 'a'`.  As a demonstration : `SELECT 'a,b,c' = 'a'`  will return 0 (FALSE). We expect that because the two strings are not equal. As I suggested in my previous comment, we can use MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function, as a demonstration  `SELECT FIND_IN_SET('a','a,b,c')` will return 1. Evaluated in boolean context, a nonzero value is considered TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `FIND_IN_SET` in your query if you are storing comma-separated values

```
    SELECT 
        t.id, t.tags 
    FROM mytable t 
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET('a',t.tags) 
    ORDER BY t.id
```

or else use can use wild card like

```
        SELECT 
            t.id, t.tags 
        FROM mytable t 
        WHERE t.tags like '%a%') 
        ORDER BY t.id
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering. I have tried both of your options but still no use.